# Bootstrap Modal Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm in need of a method to load dynamic content that can change at any time. According to the Bootstrap documentation

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.htm" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

is making use of the jQuerys' **.load** only loading the content **once**. It injects the content in the modal-content div. As previously stated the content of this modal can be changed at any given time and therefore I need a different method. Any ideas?

TL;DR - I'm looking for a method that will load dynamic content (remote) every time the modal opens instead of once (default Bootstrap modal).

Answer (score 13):

If your users can tolerate the delay, reload the content whenever the show event occurs.

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $.get("remote.htm", function(data){
        $('#modal').find('.modal-content').html(data);
    })
})
```

Add error handling and parameters as needed

Comment: I'm sure they can tolerate it if there's a loading element.

Answer (score 11):

You can properly clear the modal's cache using:

```
$('#your-modal').removeData('bs.modal');
```

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/7935#issuecomment-21166069
You'd probably want to do that in an event handler for the modal's `hidden.bs.modal` event.

Though you're probably better off using client-side templating and a little custom JavaScript to load the necessary data, instead of using `data-remote` in the first place. Especially since **[Bootstrap has deprecated the `remote` modal option](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034)**.

Answer (score 3):

this guy has a dirty but working solution: http://www.whiletrue.it/how-to-update-the-content-of-a-modal-in-twitter-bootstrap/

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

becomes:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#modal .modal-body').load('remote.html',function(e){$('#modal').modal('show');});">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Using this way the dialog will not be shown, because method .modal is not defined for type Object. I tried using this:
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"><a href="javascript:$('#modal .modal-content').load('i.php?id=MY_ID',function(e){$('#modal');});" class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" alt="info" title="Show infos"></a></button>
which will show the dialog, but content will only be updated if i click on the icon and not in the entire button.