# Bootstrap modal load entire HTML from external file

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Using: Bootstrap 4.1.3

Here is one solution but this is not exactly what i am looking for:
[Bootstrap Modal Dynamic Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863462/bootstrap-modal-dynamic-content)

I am getting the content (the entire modal html) from an external file and then i need to show it as a modal.

How to display `data` in the modal

```
$.get("test.html", function(data) {
    ???
});
```

I am trying to avoid this alternate approach, where i can append a div to body, put `data` in it and then do modal.

```
$.get("test.html", function(data) {
    //$('<div />', { id: 'holdy' }).appendTo('body');

    var $holdyDiv = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
    $holdyDiv.attr('id', 'holdy');

    //append data 
    $holdyDiv.innerHtml(data);

    //do modal
    $('#divInData').modal('show');  
});
```

Forgot to mention, this call is happening once the page has finished loading.

Comment: Why not `$('#divInData .modal-content').html(data)`?

Comment: `divInData` is the parent div, coming from `test.html`.

Comment: Well if the modal is in test.html, you may not be able to open it unless you append it to the body.

Comment: Well that is exactly what i am trying to accomplish. There should be a way to trigger modal with dynamic content, i am missing something very simple here.

Comment: You want to execute a Javascript function on an element not present in the document body. I'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain why the various answers in the other modal question or [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934494/171456) doesn't work?

Comment: @Zim i have my `data`, now how to show it in the bootstrap modal without first appending it to the body. Please take a look at the first snippet of code.

Comment: Why do you have to append it to the body? Just append it to `$('modal-body')` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763090/bootstrap-4-with-remote-modal/48934494#48934494

Comment: @Zim `modal-body` needs to be available in the dom... `modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("remote"));`. Am i missing something here?

Comment: So the *entire* modal html is in test.html? The question says modal "content".

Comment: Yes and this modal needs to be displayed once the page has finished loading.

Comment: @learning... Ah so the entire modal is in another location. Hmm

Comment: Yes, thats my issue and these guys i am working with... can't put that here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use jQuery **`$.load`** instead of `$.get` which allows you to specify the selector for the  remote modal. Then all you need to do is:

```
$('body').load("test.html #myModal",function(){
   $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Either way the Modal HTML *must* be added to the DOM of the "host" page that's loading the modal.

**Demo:** 
https://www.codeply.com/go/AQazBWdsrZ ("host" page)
https://www.codeply.com/go/sE77hS1hHs ("remote" page - modal HTML only)

Comment: Very interesting approach. Led me to this official docs on [loading page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). +1

Answer (score 2):

How about updating the modal contents on [`show.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events) event?

**show.bs.modal**

> This event fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

At this point, you could manipulate the contents before the modal is displayed, and `shown.bs.modal` triggers.

```js
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  const id = e.relatedTarget.dataset.postid;
  
  $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(data => {
      $('.modal-title', this).text(data.title);
      $('.modal-body', this).html(data.body);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-postid="1">
  Launch demo modal #1
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-postid="2">
  Launch demo modal #2
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `modal-body` needs to be available in the dom. In my case, i have the data from remote url as html. I need to show this html as a modal.

Comment: @learning... It *is* available in the DOM when you first trigger the modal visibility. From there, you should be able to do something like: `$('.modal-body', this).html(__your_html_data__)`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this call is happening once the page has finished loading.

Comment: @learning... I believe that should make no difference. If you inspect the `.modal` element, you could see that it is there, only set to `display:none` by CSS. Unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: My full modal structure is coming from the test.html file

Comment: @learning... OK, got ya. So I'm assuming it is full modal structure including an **empty** `.modal-body` that you need to update with dynamic contents.

Comment: It has every thing, including content, buttons, hml and classes applied to the markup. All i need to do is, read that file and display it as a modal.

Comment: Well, in that case, have you perhaps tried `$.get("test.html", function(data) { $(data).modal(); }` ...?

Comment: No, i didn't test with that.

Comment: @learning... Please do, and let me know if it works. I think it should, given the response of the Ajax call is the modal HTML itself.

Comment: How pass a local HTML file to open in the modal?